# Setting USPS and recaptcha overrides breaks site

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I've successfully set several overrides in civicrm.setting.php according to https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/. However, both Recatpcha and the USPS Address standardization tool break the site. Setting USPS provider line does work.

I'm doing this on a WP multisite on CiviCRM 5.20.0.

```
// Set USPS standardization 
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['address_standardization_provider'] = USPS; 
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['address_standardization_userid'] = ***; 
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['address_standardization_url'] = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/shippingapi.dll';

// Misc
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['recaptchaPublicKey'] = ***;
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['recaptchaPrivateKey'] =***;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break the site" is there an error message?

Comment: WSOD, it was a syntax error. Putting as answer.

Answer (score 1):

My syntax was wrong I needed to use tick marks around the values.